# HashMap is returning "null" for jUnit test

Tags: java, junit

I'm working on a java homework where we have to create a "Project class" then fill specified methods so that they work, this will be tested by a jUnit class.

So i have my Project class like this:

```
public class Project {

    private String name;
    private Calendar start=null;
    private Calendar end=null;


    public Project(Calendar start, Calendar end)
    {
        this.start=start;
        this.end=end;
    }
 }
```

then a createProject method like:

```
public static final HashMap<String, Project> proj_map = new HashMap<>();


@Override
public boolean createProject(String projectName, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {

    try {
        proj_map.put(projectName,new Project(startDate,endDate));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public ArrayList<String> getProjectNames() {
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(proj_map.keySet());
    return keys;
}
```

and the jUnit test class:

```
class CreateHappyPath{
    @Test
    void createProject() {
        assertEquals(true, api.createProject( "p1",new GregorianCalendar(2019,5,12), new GregorianCalendar(2019,6,13)));
        ArrayList<String> al =new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("p1");
        assertEquals(al,api.getProjectNames());
    }
```

but if i run this, my jUnit result is:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <[p1]> but was: <[p1,p2]>
```

Comment: Most likely an error in `getProjectNames()`. Can you paste its implementation?

Comment: Once you put more than one project in the map, note that list equality depends not only on the members, but on their order. One alternative is to compare sets instead of lists.

Comment: why the hashmap?  Seems like you'd want an array of type <project>.   Do the project names need to be unique?

Comment: most probably u are using same api object for several tests.

Comment: i am using HashMap cuz there are more methods like: deleteProject , changeProjectname, ListProject etc. then it is easier search for a Project.Also the Projectnames are unique, so a HashMap is good for this case i think.

Comment: @c63Coupe Why is `proj_map` a static field? Do you have a unit test where you use the name `"p2"`? Please edit your question to include the full source code of your unit test and the full source code of your `api` class/object.

Comment: What @IvanLymar said.  Since the code provided has no occurrence of "p2", there must be other code which is doing a put on "p2" to the mapping.  Since the code which was presented is unit test code, the most likely candidate for "other code" is another unit test.  Very probably, you have another unit test which adds "p2" to the mapping, and your failing test sees that because the mapping is static.

Comment: Oh thanks , it is working now, "static" was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that assertEquals behaves the same way as assertSame when the equals method is not overridden. Update your test to check the size of the collection and/or each element of the collection like that:

```
 assertEquals(al.size(),api.getProjectNames().size());
 assertTrue(al.containsAll(api.getProjectNames()));
```

Please be advised, that the order of the collections can vary and still pass the test. If you need the order to match as well, sort collections and check every item one by one.

Comment: The equals() method *is* overridden, in a superclass of ArrayList.

Comment: Agreed, however, after checking the implementation of getProjectNames(), it becomes more likely that the test fails due to the incorrect test case.